# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 189000 into shape (28,28,1)

Tags: python, numpy

Code:

```
import deepneuralnet as net
import random 
import tflearn.datasets.mnist as mnist
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
model = net.model
path_to_model = 'final-model.tflearn'
path_to_image = 'unlucky-13.jpg' # Change this to the file path/name of the image file you want to use
model.load(path_to_model)
# Load image (normalized)
print ('hello')
print (io.imread(path_to_image).shape)
x = io.imread(path_to_image).reshape((28, 28, 1)).astype(np.float) / 255
print ('hello')
print (x)
print ('hello')
result = model.predict([x])[0] # Predict
prediction = result.index(max(result)) # The index represents the number predicted in this case
print("Prediction", prediction)
```

when i am running this code error is

```
x = io.imread(path_to_image).reshape((28, 28, 1)).astype(np.float) / 255
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 189000 into shape (28,28,1)
```

Comment: Your image `unlucky-13.jpg` is really unlucky. It is not of the correct shape. 
Can you tell the output of `x = io.imread(path_to_image).shape`? You might need to resize it.

Comment: @UmangGupta output is (300, 210, 3)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to input image to a classifier which takes 28x28x1 image.

But the actual input image `unlukcy-13.jpg` is of a different shape. You need to resize the image and convert it to b/w (1 channel) image before you can pass it to the classifier.

To answer specifically about the error in question, you see error because you are trying to reshape a bigger matrix (300, 210, 3) to (28,28,1) which is not possible.